# How to apply timezones to Django Model DateTimeFields

Tags: django, django-models, python-datetime, django-timezone

When a Django model contains a DateTimeField the date is always saved in UTC timezone. If you add a date that had a time zone the information is translated and will be retrieved differently. This happens even if the `TIME_ZONE` has been set in settings.py and the date was created using `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())`. The same issue happens when the date is added dynamically, like with `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` or `models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`.

How can I retrieve or save date times in the correct timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date may come out in UTC format, but you can always convert it back to your correct timezone.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

def getTimezone():
    return pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)

model.myDateTimeField.astimezone(getTimezone()) # Converts UTC to the timezone in settings.py
```

If the datetime was saved in a different timezone altogether, this would not work. Don't do that I guess.